# MySQL in-operator must match all values?

Tags: mysql, in-operator

I've made my own forum. When doing a search I want to find any threads where two (or more) specific users have participated. I came up with this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.threadid=table2.threadid 
WHERE table2.threadcontributor IN ('1','52512')
```

Before realizing that it actually means `'1' OR '52512'`.

Is there any way to make it work so that all id's has to match?

Comment: Please give your actual table structures including PK.

Comment: please post your real code or at least what are table1 and table2. my first aproach makes me join twice the thread table. please read this post and anwser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492699/how-can-i-structure-a-query-to-give-me-only-the-rows-that-match-all-values-in-a-c/7493309#7493309

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table1 
        INNER JOIN table2 
            ON table1.threadid=table2.threadid 
    WHERE table2.threadcontributor IN ('1','52512')
    GROUP BY table1.PrimaryKey
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table2.threadcontributor) = 2
```

Comment: two (or more) specific users so it should be `>=2`

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer But there are only 2 values specified in the `IN` clause. If the goal is to make sure you match all of the values listed in the `IN` clause, then the value tested in the `HAVING` should match the number of values specified for the `IN`.

Comment: @Joe - ViswanathanIyer isn't the OP.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli MartinSmith : )