# Stuck with Mysql IN Operator

Tags: mysql

I have following table given below:

```
id_attribute  id_product_attribute
1             1
13            1
4             2
13            2
```

I want to fetch `id_product_attribute` which have `id_attribute` `1` and `13`.
My query is given below:

```
SELECT id_product_attribute 
  FROM ps_product_attribute_combination 
 WHERE id_product_attribute = 1 
   AND id_attribute IN (1,13) 
 GROUP 
    BY id_product_attribute
```

The above query is also returning the `id_product_attribute` `2` as well instead of only `1`. How can I achieve this?

Can anyone please help to resolve this problem?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It is not possible. You may have some different data, other than you put in the question.

Comment: HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 (and remove the WHERE clause)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching all values in IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636061/matching-all-values-in-in-clause)

Answer (score 1):

These links may help you:

[Matching all values in IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636061/matching-all-values-in-in-clause)

And

[MySQL in-operator must match all values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505045/mysql-in-operator-must-match-all-values)

From the above you can then use:

```
SELECT id_product_attribute 
  FROM ps_product_attribute_combination 
 WHERE id_product_attribute = 1 
   AND id_attribute IN ('1','13') 
 GROUP 
    BY id_product_attribute  
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ps_product_attribute_combination.id_attribute) = 2
```

So it will return results which are *IN* both `id_attribute` but also appear in `id_attribute` column specifically twice (using the `Having` clause).

---

Alternatively:

Your query states that :

```
SELECT id_product_attribute 
  FROM ps_product_attribute_combination 
 WHERE id_product_attribute = 1
```

So really you're always selecting `id_product_attribute = 1`. So MySQL result will always be `<id_product_attribute value>`