# Laravel where condition in relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a problem for sometime.. I have a list of anime_shows and each one of them have multiple genres and I want to create a filter where a user can select only the ones that contains some specific genres.

I have 3 tables: **anime_shows**, **genres** and **anime_show_genres** (in the last one I have 2 columns **anime_show_id**, **genre_id**).

The problem with my current code is that I get all anime_shows where I have at least 1 genre, so I am using **OR** insted of **AND**.  I also tried to do a **forEach** inside of **whereHas** but is not working.

```
$anime = AnimeShow::select('id', 'slug', 'status', 'title_eng', 'title_jap', 'description', 'episodes', 'premier_date', 'status')
        ->with('media:anime_show_id,image_path');

if($request->genres){
    $genres = $request->genres ? $request->genres : [];
    $anime->whereHas('genres', function($q) use($genres){
        $q->whereIn('id',$genres);
    });
}

if($request->airing){
    $anime->whereIn('status', $request->airing);
}

$anime->search($request->search);
        
return response($anime->paginate($request->perPage, ['*'], 'page', $request->currentPage));
```

Comment: This query builds all `AND`s where is the `OR` that you mentioned?

Comment: Basically when I am using whereIn I get all shows that contains at least one genre instead of both.

Comment: `whereIn` will match any of the genres, not just all. You'll have to iterate through the genres to build up a query

Comment: @aynber There is some solutions for this without iterating in app using `joins`. Takes a little bit time to write and analyze, let's see :D

Comment: I tried to use a forEach inside whereHas and there I did:  $q->where('id', $value); but in this case works when I have just 1 genre, after I add the second one I get no results.

Comment: @Beusebiu This might answer  your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505045/mysql-in-operator-must-match-all-values, but you have to apply it in your logic inside your `whereHas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to loop the genres like this:

```php
$genres = $request->genres ?: [];

foreach ($genres as $genre) {
    $anime->whereHas('genres', function($q) use ($genre) {
        $q->where('id', $genre);
    });
}
```

It would be animes that have genere A and have genre B and so one.

Comment: YES! Till now I tried something similar, but forEach was inside whereHas and didn't  work. Thank you!