# SQL query to match multiple column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble getting my head around the following problem.

Given the following table structure and data, how might I select records that match two tags. For example:

```
+-----------------+------------------+
|  collection_id  |         tag      |
+-----------------+------------------+
|        1        |    advertising   |
|        1        |     tutorials    |
|        2        |    advertising   |
|        2        |       coding     |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

If I search for advertising && tutorials, it should return `collection_id` = 1, and not `collection_id` = 2.

Any pointers most welcome.

Comment: What you'd like to get: scalar `collection_id`? Or multiple values are possible?

Comment: I had a similar question at one point http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492699/how-can-i-structure-a-query-to-give-me-only-the-rows-that-match-all-values-in-a In this case you would have a csv list of TAG's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT collection_ID
FROM tableName
WHERE tag IN ('advertising','tutorials')
GROUP BY collection_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960fd/2)

If `unique` constraint was not specified on the tag for each `collection_ID`

```
SELECT collection_ID
FROM tableName
WHERE tag IN ('advertising','tutorials')
GROUP BY collection_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/960fd/3)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I copied across more data, and it seems that the query isn't returning as I'd expected. Please see here > http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/021e8/3/0

Comment: no, you have extra spaces on the tags [see here (*click here*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/021e8/9)

Comment: anyone care to explain about the downvote? :D thank you. much appreciated. (*no pressure if you don't want hehe*)