# How to select records where their statuses are just in a set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Suppose I have following tables
`Person table` and `personStatus table`.

```
declare @Persons table
(PersonId int)

insert into @Persons select 10   
insert into @Persons select 11    
insert into @Persons select 12   
insert into @Persons select 13  
insert into @Persons select 14    

declare @PersonStatus table
(id int,statuss int)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(14,4)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(10,0)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(10,0)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(11,1)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(10,1)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(11,2)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(12,0)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(12,1)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(12,2)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(13,1)
insert into @PersonStatus (id,statuss) values(13,3)
```

Now I want to find person IDs that  of their statuses are just in this set {0,1,2}
result is ---> 10,11,12

How to do it?

Comment: If you ever plan on your "limiting" criteria being dynamic (or a parameter), check out the question I asked awhile back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492699/how-can-i-structure-a-query-to-give-me-only-the-rows-that-match-all-values-in-a.  It is the same as yours except my input was a CSV string of limit sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    PersonStatus
GROUP   BY ID
HAVING  SUM(CASE WHEN statuss IN (0, 1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 AND
        SUM(CASE WHEN statuss NOT IN (0, 1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2180ee/5)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID
FROM @PersonStatus PT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @PersonStatus WHERE statuss not in (0,1,2) AND id=PT.id)
```

Comment: What if the result set is `{0,1,4}` .With your query ,the result will include `id` for `status=2` and `status=3`

Comment: @praveen then replace `statuss>2` with `statuss in (0,1,4)`